# Problem with selective filtering and error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r, filtering

I have the table and program below. I run it and it processes the data from the file I choose, deletes a bunch of data never used, then a pop-up comes up and I can choose multiple selections. In an example using the data below, I choose Site 1 and 3 and then I select all the choices in the next two pop-ups. I was hoping to see all of the data from Sites 1 and 3. But it erases, for example, Analyte 6 from Site 1 on the 4th of March. I am almost positive this is from my i values, but just can't see the problem and can't find anything similar in my help searches

Data Example:

| Project | sampletype | SpecificMethod | Analyte | ClientMatrix | Sampled | tResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 1 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 1 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 1 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 1 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 2 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 2 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 2 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 2 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 3 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 16.6 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 3 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 76 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 3 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 27.8 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 1 | Analyte 3 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 21 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.133 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.236 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.179 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.192 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.404 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.619 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.57 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.565 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.0529 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.0428 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/3/2020 | ND |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.664 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 0.784 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 1.32 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/3/2020 | 1.17 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.511 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.43 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.381 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.314 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.93 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 2.38 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.35 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.06 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.229 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.241 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.119 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 0.0825 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.99 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 2.54 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.72 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/9/2020 | 1.61 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.198 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.269 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.249 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 4 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.259 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.12 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.12 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.17 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 5 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.753 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.169 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.13 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.128 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 6 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 0.0661 |
| Site 1 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.04 |
| Site 2 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.15 |
| Site 3 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.2 |
| Site 4 | Long | Method 3 | Analyte 7 | Air | 4/15/2020 | 1.2 |

The program:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

fileIn <- file.choose(new = FALSE)

# Pull data from excel data and make dataframe (df) named, in this case,  Elem
Elem <- read_xls(paste0(fileIn), col_names = TRUE, na = c("void", "VOID"), col_types = NULL)

# tResult is a character. This makes it a number
Elem$tResult <- as.numeric(Elem$tResult)

# Sampled is a character. This makes it a date in local time
Elem$Sampled <- parse_date_time(Elem$Sampled, '%m/%d/%Y', tz = 'Etc/GMT-8')

# Sort the data 
Elem[with(Elem, order("Project", "Sampled", "SpecificMethod", "Analyte")), ]

# Remove rows with specific criteria, ex. Blanks
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$ClientMatrix=="PM 10 - HV" | Elem$sampletype=="Blank - Equipment"),]
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$sampletype=="Pre-deployment Check" | Elem$Project=="Special Projects" | Elem$Project=="Sample Media Lot Blanks"),]
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$Project=="Predeployment Equipment Check" | Elem$Project=="Project"),]
Elem <- Elem[rowSums(is.na(Elem)) != ncol(Elem),]

# Make new value named "Location" from the column named "Project" and choose one or multiple sites (with CTRL or Shift)
# Assign integer values to the locations (sites) you chose
Location <- unique(Elem$Project)
x <- select.list(Location, preselect = NULL, multiple = T, title = "Locations? Hold SHIFT or CTRL for multiple",  graphics = TRUE)
i <- with(Elem, match(x, unique(Location)))

# Remove all rows of data that are NOT at a site you chose
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$Project != Location[i]),]
Elem <- Elem[rowSums(is.na(Elem)) != ncol(Elem),]

# Make new value named "Method" from the column named "SpecificMethod" and choose multiple Methods (with CTRL or Shift)
Method <- unique(Elem$SpecificMethod)
y <- select.list(Method, preselect = NULL, multiple = T, title = "Method? Hold SHIFT or CTRL for multiple",  graphics = TRUE)
j <- with(Elem, match(y, unique(SpecificMethod)))

# Remove all data that are NOT at an analysis method you chose
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$SpecificMethod != Method[j]),]
Elem <- Elem[rowSums(is.na(Elem)) != ncol(Elem),]

# Make new value named "Pollutant" from the column named "Analyte" and choose multiple pollutants (with CTRL or Shift)
Pollutant <- unique(Elem$Analyte)
z <- select.list(Pollutant, preselect = NULL, multiple = T, title = "Pollutant? Hold SHIFT or CTRL for multiple",  graphics = TRUE)
k <- with(Elem, match(z, unique(Analyte)))

# Remove all data that are NOT a pollutant you chose
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$Analyte != Pollutant[k]),]
Elem <- Elem[rowSums(is.na(Elem)) != ncol(Elem),]

# Display df
View(Elem)
```

When I do this in Excel, I filter the data and then copy/paste data into a new sheet. I want to instead automate this with R in a simple series of steps. I am not an expert by any means in R, and I have piecemealed this program from multiple sources so it is a little uneven. I started with using the menu() function in selecting my criteria (like my specific location), but it only allows for one selection.

The problems:

- My raw data comes out as an Excel file and I have to do a lot of post-processing in Excel to make the data shareable.
- In R, I want to be able to select different criteria each time based on the Project, Method and Analyte.
- I want to be able to select multiple criteria when filtering the data (ex. Choose Site 1 and Site 2, but exclude the other sites while keeping all of the data, including the ND data).

The errors:

- When I run the program and select the first subset of data (based on Location), I lose a lot of my data associated with that selection. If I choose two sites (out of 4) for example, it deletes a large part of the data from those sites along with all the other sites I didn't choose (the latter being what I am shooting for, the former being a huge issue). I have a feeling it has to do with my `i` values, but am not totally sure.
- I get the dreaded

  ```
    In Elem$Project != x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
  ```

  error when I am trying to delete rows not associated with my Location choices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CJCC from another forum for the answer.

I needed to replace

```
Location <- unique(Elem$Project)
x <- select.list(Location, preselect = NULL, multiple = T, title = "Locations? Hold SHIFT or CTRL for multiple",  graphics = TRUE)
i <- with(Elem, match(x, unique(Location)))

# Remove all rows of data that are NOT at a site you chose
Elem <- Elem[!(Elem$Project != Location[i]),]
Elem <- Elem[rowSums(is.na(Elem)) != ncol(Elem),]
```

with

```
Location <- unique(Elem$Project)
x <- select.list(Location, preselect = NULL, multiple = T, title = "Locations? Hold SHIFT or CTRL for multiple",  graphics = TRUE)

# Remove all rows of data that are NOT at a site you chose
Elem <- Elem[Elem$Project %in% x,]
Elem <- Elem[rowSums(is.na(Elem)) != ncol(Elem),]
```

Other Help Post at https://community.rstudio.com/t/code-help-for-novice-trying-to-customize-output-of-xls-based-data-frame/134451 (post at link will erase after 21 days so May 6, 2022)